# Runtime error being caused by trs in code

Tags: html, excel, vba, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to pull cash flows for a bunch of companies in a folder I have created. I am pulling the information from market watch. An example of the websites I am pulling tables from is https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/cash-flow. All of the Ticker symbols for each company is in column A. My code is breaking on the following line with an error of "Runtime Error "91".

```
Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

I know that there are trs in the HTML code. Also, I ran the code for a couple of the companies) and then when I went to do it again the code never got past the first one (I didn't have the save and close functions in there the first time because I was testing it so I exited out of each of the workbooks I did and I didn't save them).

```
Public Sub Companies()
Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, hTable As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim Last As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 572 Step -1

M = 0

Workbooks.Open "C:***\Desktop\Stock Portfolio\Stock Valuations\Temporary Valuations\" & Cells(i, "A").Value & ".xlsx"

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set ws = Workbooks(Cells(i, "A").Value).Sheets.Add(After:= _
         Workbooks(Cells(i, "A").Value).Sheets(Workbooks(Cells(i, "A").Value).Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Cash Flow"

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Set html = New HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/" & Cells(i, "A").Value & "/financials/cash-flow", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With

ThisWorkbook.Activate
With html
    .body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
    WriteTable hTable, 1, Workbooks(Cells(i, "A").Value).Sheets("Cash Flow")
End With

ThisWorkbook.Activate

M = 3

With html
    .body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("tbody")(1)
    WriteTable hTable, 1, Workbooks(Cells(i, "A").Value).Sheets("Cash Flow")
End With
Workbooks(Cells(i, "A")).Save
Workbooks(Cells(i, "A")).Close
Next
End Sub
```

I used the code above and then I used the public code below (where the problem occurs) to get the table.

```
Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As Object, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
startRow = (M * 20) + 1
r = startRow
With ws
    Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each tr In tRow
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each td In tCell
            .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
            c = c + 1
        Next td
    Next tr
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Use Option Explicit and declare all your variables. If M is a global variable make that clear otherwise it needs to be passed to the WriteTable function. 2) Have you inspected sResponse? I can see what looks like a captcha blocking the way. So, hTable ends up as nothing.

Comment: @QHarr  How was I able to do it once before if there was a captcha. Just curious to become more knowledgeable.

Comment: you were never able to do it once before if there was a captcha but your prior activity may have led to you now being a suspected bot. In which case my last option may actually be a possibility though you would have to keep alternating in the hope that would work; not something I would do personally.

Comment: @QHarr Could I run it through a vpn?

Comment: You can try but there are lots of ways for a site to be configured to recognise bots that goes beyond IP and user agent especially if you are doing lots of requests in a short period of time. If you do try as a minimum you will need to consider some of these other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the ideal answer but always inspect the response you are getting. Furthermmore, check whether hTable is nothing. If I inspect the response I notice the site is on the look out for *bots* and blocking with a captcha.

> Pardon Our Interruption...
>
> As you were browsing www.marketwatch.com something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this
>   might happen:
>
> You're a power user moving through this website with super-human
>   speed. You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser. A third-party
>   browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript
>   from running. Additional information is available in this support
>   article.
>
> After completing the CAPTCHA below, you will immediately regain access
>   to www.marketwatch.com.

If this is indeed the case for you, you have a few options:

1) Search for an alternative source of the info

2) Use browser automation (selenium basic) and hope that this alone, or with some appropriate waits may get you there

3) Change IP and user agent. If you were able to originally run XHR against this page then it may be that now you have been added to a watch list for suspected bots by the site. Alternating IP and user-agent is not something I would do.